# Who can access one's flight itinerary?

Tags: air-travel, airports, international-travel, travel-agents

Someone with experience in a travel agency or who works at an airport may be able to answer my  question.

My ex-girlfriend works with the airport authority. Last time I traveled, she surprised/stalked me at my regular airport bar. She told me that she found out my travel itinerary. It might be coincidence or that she was told by some mutual friends.

If she knows my name or passport number, is she able to access my information?

In three days, I am travelling with my current girlfriend to visit my parents. We arrive and depart from the same airport where my ex works.

Supplemental info :

My ex-girlfriend has friends/colleagues who work in airlines check-in/reservation and others. She has access to the system (because of her job role). I can't say to what extent she has access. But to what I can recollect she helped mutual friends' family by providing some info when they traveled (one occasion kids travelling and another occasion friends older parents travelling). I can't say if she has direct access or she requested the info from some colleague who has access.

Is it actually possible for her to find my flying details?

Comment: Nice Q but voting to close as "unclear what you are asking" until you specify what @pnuts has asked for. Also use the account you posted this Q with to edit and comment.

Comment: _Anyone that has your 6-char booking code and your last name_ can not only see all details, but also cancel your flight or change your seat.

Comment: @pnuts my fault; I added the 'or' which OP did put in his comment. I agree; her role is relevant for both her direct access, or having other people do it on her behalf.

Comment: @pnuts I took it to mean that either she has direct access (airline or gov't employee) or she works in a business or shop and asked someone with authorization to do it for her. Hopefully, OP will clarify that point.

Comment: Please sign in and edit as the OP rather than trying to do it as a new account with the same name. We can not be sure it is the same person that way.

Comment: Do you have a regular airline your ex would know about? Did you post on social media about your trip? Depending on the number of possible flights your ex may have been making an educated guess.

Answer (score 4):

Consult the [Galileo pocket guide](http://travelport.com.pk/media/flv/video692330Galileo_Pocket_Guide.pdf) to find:

> RETRIEVE BOOKING FILE

- By record locator
- By name
- By infant name
- By pax name & dep date
- By flight #s & pax name
- By flight #, dep date & pax name

It is definitely possible to retrieve a PNR by just the name of the booking person or the passenger name and the departure date.

Edit: this is corroborated by the [Air Canada kiosk instructions](http://www.aircanada.com/en/travelinfo/airport/expresscheckin/) which say:

> Insert a magnetic-stripe Aeroplan, Star Alliance or payment card (Payment card information is used for identification purposes only: no fee will be charged and your payment card information will not be retained.)

There's nothing they could get from a payment card except for the name which could lead to the itin.

Or check [Iberia Express](https://www.iberiaexpress.com/en/general-info/passenger-information/at-the-airport/automated-check-in-machines) instructions:

> Enter your name or booking reference and follow the instructions on the screen.

*Or*.